# Independent and Identically Distributed n Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Q) Let $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},....,X_{n}$ be independent and identically distributed with $P(X_{i} = 1) = P(X_{i} = -1) = p$ and $P(X_{i} = 0) =1-2p$ for all $i=1,2,3,...n$. Define

$a_{n} = P\left ( \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}=1\right )$$,\;$$b_{n} = P\left ( \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}=-1\right ),\;$$c_{n} =P\left ( \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}=0\right )$

Which of the following is true as $n$ tends to infinity ?

(A) $a_n \rightarrow 1/3,\;b_n \rightarrow 1/3,\;c_n \rightarrow 1/3\; $

(B) $a_n \rightarrow p,\;b_n \rightarrow p,\;c_n \rightarrow 1-2p\; $

(C) $a_n \rightarrow 1/2,\;b_n \rightarrow 1/2,\;c_n \rightarrow 0\; $

(D) $a_n \rightarrow 0,\;b_n \rightarrow 0,\;c_n \rightarrow 1\; $

**My Attempt :-**

Here , $a_{n} = P\left ( \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}=1\right )= $$\mathbb{P}((X_{1}\times X_{2}\times X_{3}\times .......\times X_{n}) = 1)$

Since, $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},....,X_{n}$ are independent random variables. So, I can rewrite $a_n=\mathbb{P}((X_{1}\times X_{2}\times X_{3}\times .......\times X_{n}) = 1)$ as $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=1)\times \mathbb{P}(X_{2}=1)\times \mathbb{P}(X_{3}=1)\times .......\times \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 1) = p^{n}$

Now, here $\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=1) + \mathbb{P}(X_{i}=-1) + \mathbb{P}(X_{i}=0) = p+p+1-2p = 1$ for all $i=1,2,...n$ but $p$ can’t be equal to $1$ because if $p=1$ then $\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=0) = 1-2(1) = -1$ which is not possible because probability must be between $0$ and $1$(including both).

Now, If I consider $0< p< 1$ then $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ both tend to zero but $c_{n}$ also tends to zero and If I consider $p=0$ then $a_n$ and $b_n$ both tend to zero because $0^{\infty }$ is a determinate form which is equal to zero but $c_n$ is in indeterminate form. I think my approach is wrong because I am not getting any option here. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that $p\ne\frac12$. An infinite sequence of realisations of the given $X_i$ will almost surely contain at least one instance of $X_i=0$ because $P(X_i=0)>0$. Once this realisation occurs, $\prod_{i=1}^nX_i$ instantly becomes $0$ regardless of all other realisations, so $c_n=1$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$ and the answer is (D).

If $p=\frac12$ then it is easy to see that $\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=\pm1$ with equal probabilities for the sign, so the answer is (C).

Comment: What if $p = 1/2$?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist That'd probably be ruled out by the question ($P(X_i=0)\ne0$, so if it was 0 it would not be listed), but in that case (C) would be true.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be ruled out in the formulation given in the question. I guess my point is that it’d have been nice for your answer to account for this case.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist there.

Comment: Great! (Though I already upvoted a while ago.)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Can you please tell me where I was doing mistake ?

Comment: @ankit In a finite sequence there might be, say, two realisations of $-1$ and the product of $X_i$ would still be $1$. The equation you wrote after "So I can rewrite..." is false because there are more possibilities. Similarly, you have $P(\neg c_n)=(2p)^n\to0$ and so $P(c_n)\to1$.

Comment: @Shalop done. ${}{}{}$